# Unable to Change UILabel from Page Title via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview, uilabel, page-title

I'm trying to get to change the UILabel `pageTitle` to whatever the title of the page displayed on the UIWebView is. I'm returning no warnings or errors, it just simply isn't changing.

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate> {
    UIWebView *_webView;
    UILabel *_pageTitle;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *pageTitle;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    _pageTitle.text = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
}
```

**Screenshot of IB**

[image: Interface Builder]

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. Try self.pageTitle.text = [_webView ...];
2. In the delegate callback method, change the name of the argument to webView1 and try using webView1 javaScript ...
3. Make sure that you have set [webView.setDelegate:self]
4. Is the label wired from the xib file to the class

It can be any of the above reasons

Comment: No, none of the above seemed to work :(. Possibly number 4, but I'm not quite sure what you mean. The UILabel is connected to `pageTitle` within Files Owner. Thanks for trying though man. +1

Comment: Are you sure. I have a sample project which I can email, if that can be of any help.

Comment: Well if you already have it created, then that would be great! :)